# Contact link in stackexchange.com return page not found

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, footer

Clicking on the [Contact](https://stackexchange.com/contact) link from the https://stackexchange.com footer return the **Page Not Found** page.

But the **Contact** link from other pages redirect to the correct page.

[image: Contact link error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

A fix has been pushed and will be deployed shortly.

Please allow some time for cache expiration (~1 hour).

Comment: Now the *Contact* link is mapped with [`https://stackexchange.com/about/contact`](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact) and it redirect to [`https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact`](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact). This is the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, this is by design. Arguably, should go directly to `https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact`, but `/about/contact` might end up being a thing on se.com, so...